use SQL Trino and regexp_extract to extract string after pattern before comma
I'm trying to extract the characters AFTER 'wc:' and before the next comma.
So far, I have tried this (using SQL Trino):
regexp_extract(gcam, '(wc:\s*)[^,]*') as gcam_wc

which returns wc: and the desired number, e.g. wc:211
Any help how not to extract the "wc:" but only the character following it up to the next comma would be much appreciated!

You captured the wrong part, you need wc:\s*([^,]*)

thanks, unfortunately the result still includes the "wc:"

Right, because you are returning the whole value. Return Group 1 value only.

You need to capture the right part of the pattern and also tell the regexp_extract function to return the Group 1 value:
regexp_extract(gcam, 'wc:\s*([^,]*)', 1)

See the Trino regexp_extract function documentation.

regexp_extract(string, pattern, group) → varchar
Finds the first occurrence of the regular expression pattern in string and returns the capturing group number group:
SELECT regexp_extract('1a 2b 14m', '(\d+)([a-z]+)', 2); -- 'a'

